# Different tools for profiling and some kind of monitoring of hadoop map reduce programs in java?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, profiling

I am looking for tools which can give me in-depth analysis. It should basically be able to profile my mapreduce jobs.

Comment: This question is offtopic to SO, however you can ask it here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

One such tool which I know of is Jumbune. It has several features like HDFS Data Validation, Mapreduce job profiling and guess what, it has several mapreduce debugging capabilities too which I think is exclusive.

More on jumbune can be found here: http://jumbune.org/

The biggest benefit is, its open-source: https://github.com/impetus-opensource/jumbune